# Cannot initialize ChromiumWebBrowser inside a JSB-bounded class

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have followed this [steps](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#async-javascript-binding-jsb) to setup JSB. In my bounded-class, I need to return the source of an API request (I cannot, therefore, use GetPageSourceAsync because no JS context is ever created). So, I use the *trick* of copying and immediately pasting the page content to a string variable (see *result*). This code is not working, I get the following exception:

```
The ChromiumWebBrowser instance creates the underlying Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) browser instance in an async fashion. The undelying CefBrowser instance is not yet initialized. Use the IsBrowserInitializedChanged event and check the IsBrowserInitialized property to determine when the browser has been initialized.
```

which is happening on `bro.SelectAll();`:

```
public class boundClass
{
        ChromiumWebBrowser bro;

        public boundClass()
        {
            bro = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com");
        }

        public string getAuthSource(string url)
        {
            string source = String.Empty;

            bro.Load(url);

            while (bro.IsLoading)
            {

            }

            bro.SelectAll();
            bro.Copy();
            string result = Clipboard.GetText();
            Clipboard.Clear();

            return result;
        }

    }
```

What's the problem? The `ChromiumWebBrowser` seems well-initialized to me...

Comment: You've already asked tgis on Gitter, please don't cross post in future.  Instead post your question here and post a link on Gitter (if you absolutely have to, posting here only is just fine). Nobody viewing this question will see my response on Gitter,  make sense?

Comment: it's not a cross post if it's on a completely different forum.  If it is, kindly post the link to that forum instead (if you want to help someone else).